# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter

I want to filter components key value. I am using `filter`for this. But I am getting error:
`TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Key value is div's key value.

I have tried to use it as a function or as a constant, but still getting same error.

```
getComponent(key){
    return this.props.children!.filter(component => {
      return component.key === key;
    });
  }
```

I am expecting to get my component's key value filtered. Maybe anyone had same problem?

I am using React-typescript

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, strings, numbers, booleans, and various other of the types listed for `this.props.children` don't have a function called `filter`. So you need to first ensure that you're dealing with an array, and then use a type assertion to tell TypeScript that:

```
if (Array.isArray(this.props.children)) {
    return (this.props.children as ReactNodeArray).filter(component => component.key === key);
}
// ...handle the fact it's not an array...
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem some weeks ago, and I used `React.Children` to iterate over nested childrens passed to a component.

Here you have the code I made:

```
public renderByKey(childElement, key) {
    return React.Children.map(childElement, child => {
        if (child != null) {
            if (child.props != undefined) {
                if (typeof (child.type) !== 'string') {
                    if (child.props.key != undefined && child.props.key === key) {
                        return child;
                    }
                }
                if (child.props.children != undefined) {
                    return this.renderByKey(child.props.children,key);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I know the inconveniences about recursivity, but I used it with other props (not with key as your case), and worked perfect for me.